# Checkmark in checkbox not appearing when changing CSS

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I'm trying to change the size,color,etc... of a checkbox using CSS. I have everything formatted the way I want aside from when the box is checked. When the box is checked, the check/tick mark does not appear and nothing seems to happen. However, I know it works otherwise because I can set the background color to change, and it works then.

Does adding "content: '✔';" do anything in the CSS as far as what I'm trying to accomplish, or am I using it incorrectly?

For example:

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked {
    content: '✔';
    background-color:white;
}
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b0rcbvaf/) that demonstrates the background color of the checkbox changing.

[Here's another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jarxo3t8/) of what I'm trying to do by using a check mark when the box is checked.

**Edit - I'm using chrome and that seems to be the issue. I checked in firefox and it works**

Knowing this, what can I do to accomplish what I have described?

Comment: FYI the check does not appear to work in Chrome

Comment: I probably should have noted that. I am using chrome. I didn't think it could be a browser issue....well, just checked in firefox and it works. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) property currently only applies to [pseudo elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) such as [`:before`/`:after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements).

Checkbox elements are notoriously difficult to style (not all browsers allow you to specify a `height`/`width`; also, they are self enclosed elements, meaning that they *cannot* contain pseudo elements.

Therefore, the most common approach for creating custom checkboxes is to *hide* the `input`/checkbox element and style a succeeding `label` element via a pseudo element. For instance:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
<label for="checkbox1"></label>
```

Utilize the [adjacent sibling combinator, `+`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators), in order to change the styling of the custom `label` element/pseudo element:

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {}
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/wqf6fmrv/)

This will get you started. Style accordingly.

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}
input[type="checkbox"] + label {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
    content: '✔';
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.6em;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
<label for="checkbox1"></label>
```

Comment: Another much simpler option is a background image... perhaps with an SVG in a data-uri.

Comment: It's probably also worth noting that input elements don't support `before` and `after` pseudo elements since it is a contentless tag.

Comment: @Godwin Good point. Precisely why a `label` element is used in this case.

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly. Quite a strange solution, but I'm glad it works.

Answer (score 1):

As Josh Crozier stated `content` only works for `:before` and `:after`. And you're trying to add it to the `input`. You can create a check mark using css transitions for a nicer look:

**HTML**

```
<div class="custom">
   <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="checkmark" name="check" />
   <label for="checkmark"></label>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.custom {
    position: relative;
}

.custom label {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: double 2px #8C8C8C;
    background-color:white;
    color:#FFF;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width:35px;
    height:35px;

}

.custom label:after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 14px;
    height: 8px;
    background: transparent;
    top: 8px;
    left: 8px;
    border: 3px solid #000;
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.custom label:hover::after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=30);
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.custom input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
}
```

## [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jarxo3t8/4/)